# Fullcalendar - Can we add custom data to our event Json Data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, fullcalendar

I want to send a type in my Event Json Response.

Here is my code:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

eventSources: [ 

{"id":"46_l","title":"CustomEvent-Chargement","start":"2013-12-02","end":"2013-12-03","className":"customEventsClass","type":1},
{"id":"46_d","title":"Custom Event-Livraison","start":"2013-12-11","end":"2013-12-12","className":"customEventsClass","type":2}

]

});
```

You see I send a **type** in JSON Response array, is this possible? What parameter can we use for sending our custom data?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add more fields/data to a FullCalendar day](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20070777/add-more-fields-data-to-a-fullcalendar-day)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try It with `events:` instead of `eventSources:`

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

 events: [ 

{"id":"46_l","title":"CustomEvent-Chargement","start":"2013-12-02","end":"2013-12-03","className":"customEventsClass","type":1},
{"id":"46_d","title":"Custom Event-Livraison","start":"2013-12-11","end":"2013-12-12","className":"customEventsClass","type":2}

]

});
```

Answer (score 14):

As per [the documentation](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/):

> ### Non-standard Fields
>
> In addition to the fields above, you may also include your own non-standard fields in each Event Object. FullCalendar will not modify or delete these fields. For example, developers often include a `description` field for use in callbacks such as [eventRender](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/).

**Example:**

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: [
        {
            title: 'My Event',
            start: '2010-01-01',
            type: 1 // Custom field
        }
    ],
    eventRender: function(event, element) {
        console.log(event.type); // Writes "1"
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

In the new version you should do this:

```
eventRender: function (info) {
    info.el.firstChild.innerHTML = info.event.extendedProps.type + " " + info.event.extendedProps.customEventsClass;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In version 4 custom data is in **extendedProps**.

In short `e.event.extendedProps`

Comment: Great that's exactly i was looking for thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass url endpoint to events as long as the url returns json response

```
            cId.fullCalendar({
             header: {
                right: '',
                center: 'prev, title, next',
                left: ''
             },

            theme: true, //Do not remove this as it ruin the design
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            editable: true,
             //it will load data from this url
            events: "{{ url('api/events') }}",
//               events: getData(),

            //Add Events
        });
```

and in your controller or function

```
  $events = $request->user()->events()->select('title','color','date')->get();

   //        dd($even,$events)
          $eventsResponse = [];
 //        created_at->format('Y-m-d')
          foreach ($events as $event)
          {
           $eventsResponse[] = [
            'title'=>$event->title,
            'color'=>$event->color,
            'start'=> Carbon::parse($event->date)->toDateTimeString(),
           ];
        }

       return $eventsResponse;
```