# Using Ajax how to populate the events data in Full Calendar?

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

I Am using FullCalender in My Django project.
 Using for loop I can able to populate the data when the script was in same HTML page but now I want to separate js file.

Comment: i suggest check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20542056/fullcalender-can-we-add-custom-data-to-our-event-json-data

Comment: @Tegito123 I am not able to get that thing could u please help me where and what to do ?